# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cxf' is defined - springboot JAVA annotation

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, cxf

I was testing  Springboot + camel JAVADSL +cxf webservice . When the spring boot application starts I am getting below mentioned exception and the application context is not getting loaded. Springboot will be loading the camel context so there no camel-context.xml . Camel router are defined in JAVADSL

```
Sep 03, 2015 5:49:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [CXFServlet] in web application [] threw load() exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cxf' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadBus(CXFServlet.java:80)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.init(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1034)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.startConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
```

Application Context class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties 
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final String CXF_URL_MAPPING = "/cxf/*";
    private static final String CXF_SERVLET_NAME = "CXFServlet";


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);

    }

@Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration =
                new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), CXF_URL_MAPPING);
        registration.setName(CXF_SERVLET_NAME);
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return registration;
    }


    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>com</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <camel.version>2.15.2</camel.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.10.Final</hibernate.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId> 
            <version>2.7.0</version> </dependency> -->




        <!-- Apache Came CXF Dependencies -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-search</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- End of Apache Came CXF Dependencies -->

        <!-- Apache Common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- camel -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf-transport</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-metrics</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-sql</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-swagger</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version> <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-gson</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> <artifactId>camel-spring-ws</artifactId> 
            <version>${camel.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId> 
            <version>${camel.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> <artifactId>camel-restlet</artifactId> 
            <version>${camel.version}</version> use the same version as your Camel core 
            version </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId> <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.spring</artifactId> 
            <version>${restlet-version}</version> </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- informix dependency -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.informix.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.com.informix.jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.JC3</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId> 
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>junit</groupId> <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
            <version>${junit.version}</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->

        <!-- LOG4J DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this bean to Application class:

```
@Bean
public SpringBus cxf() {        
    return new SpringBus();
}
```

The reason is that CXF looks for a "cxf" bean that he uses to configure the [Bus](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/bus-configuration.html), and that bean is usually declared in cxf.xml file.
Since you are using Java configuration this would be the most appropiate solution, but you could also import cxf.xml in your class with:

```
@ImportResource({ "classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a very similar question posted in this thread:

[No bean named 'cxf' is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696785/no-bean-named-cxf-is-defined)

The main thing, that CXFServlet is looking for a bean named "cxf", which should be configured via these xmls as far as I can understand it. So this is a CXF and not a Camel related error.

Hope this helps!